# Should I redirect all urls of my website to https?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect, dns

My website can be accessed 6 different ways :

1. domain.com
2. www.domain.com
3. http://domain.com/
4. http://www.domain.com/
5. https://domain.com/
6. https://www.domain.com/

Should I keep it that way or is it a better practice to point all urls to https://www.domain.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should redirect all of the traffic over SSL.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted/

Summary:

- Helps defeat WiFi eavesdropping on open networks.
- Helps defeat various types of spying on network traffic, WiFi or not.
- HTTPS isn't that expensive any more; Gmail measured SSL accounting for just 1% of CPU load and 2% of network overhead when Gmail switched everything to HTTPS.
- SSL is getting faster every year, reducing already modest costs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did :

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This way, by typing any of the 6 different urls to access my website, the server always redirects to https://www.domain.com.